# Select option for a form in html

Tags: html, css

I am creating a form but struggling to make this output, in the image I provided, which requires a user to select either "Twitter, Facebook or Google plus" but as blocks underneath each other and just needs the user to click on it and move on to the next page.

I tried making use of the select and the option function but cannot get the output as I realized that it will give me a drop-down or a scroll feature. May you please assist me?

Here is an image of what the output I am trying to achieve:

[image]

```css
.Main-Wrapper {
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 1px 10px 18px 4px #888888;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px;
}

.Main-Wrapper p {
  margin-top: -15px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.next {
  background-color: rgb(62, 196, 62);
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.previous {
  margin-left: 150px;
  background-color: rgb(62, 196, 62);
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

section {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ol,
li {
  list-style: none;
}

fieldset {
  border: none
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="Main-Wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>Social Profiles</h1>
      <p>Your presence on the social media</p>
    </header>
    <form action="">
      <fieldset>
        <ol>
          <li>
            <select name="" id="">
              <option value="">Twitter</option>
              <option value="">Facebook</option>
              <option value="">Google Plus</option>
            </select>
          </li>
        </ol>
        <section>
          <a href="#" class="previous">Previous</a>
          <a href="" class="next">Next</a>
        </section>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: use 3 styled buttons instead of form select

Comment: Don't use buttons, these should be radio buttons if the user has to select one. For multiple selection use checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use (slightly) styled radio buttons:

```js
$('input[type=radio] + label').on('click', function() {
  console.log("SUBMIT");
  // submit form
});
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]+label {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="one" name="product" />
<label for="one">First option</label>
<input type="radio" id="two" name="product" />
<label for="two">2nd option</label>
<input type="radio" id="three" name="product" />
<label for="three">3rd option</label>
```

2. select with a size:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  console.log("SUBMIT");
  // submit form here
});
```

```css
option {
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}
option:checked {
  background-color: lime;
}
select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="3">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

3. Or you can brute-force it with three `<a>`'s.

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="?value=1">Button number 1</a>
<a class="button" href="?value=2">Button number 2</a>
<a class="button" href="?value=3">Button number 3</a>
<!-- Yes, I did write a program to generate that HTML! -->
```

And then retreive it using PHP:

```php
<?php 
$locations = array(
   "option 1 url",
   "option 2 url",
   "option 3 url"
);
header("Location: " . $locations[(int) $_GET['value'] + 1]);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes much more sense and is clearly explained. Have a great day